# Numpy question regarding accessing elements

Tags: python, numpy

So I have created an array from 3 nested lists (atleast I think it is an array from 3 lists), and I want to access the three diagonal elements in it. I have the array created, but how do I access the three diagonal elements in it?

```
from numpy import *
test1 = arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
test1
```

Result:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
      [ 3,  4,  5],
      [ 6,  7,  8]],

     [[ 9, 10, 11],
      [12, 13, 14],
      [15, 16, 17]],

     [[18, 19, 20],
      [21, 22, 23],
      [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list comprehension approach:

```
>>> [np.diagonal(i) for i in test1]
[array([0, 4, 8]), array([ 9, 13, 17]), array([18, 22, 26])]
```

Comment: Sorry I had to re edit my code, and the np.diag(test1) does not work now : (

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. Here, I will highlight the use of a boolean mask.

First create the boolean 3x3 identity matrix : i.e. the diagonal is True whilst 2. every off diagonal entry is False.
Then overlay the boolean mask over your original ndarray to get the diagonals.

```
import numpy as np
test1 = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

>>> diag = np.eye(3, dtype=bool)
>>> test1[:, diag]
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 9, 13, 17],
       [18, 22, 26]])
```

As you can see, this gives a 2d array where each row is the corresponding diagonal of the zeroth, first and second 
2d array in your 3d array.

As an aside, avoid `import *`, it is the cause of many a headache because if destroys the namespace abstraction you
have. In the above example, what if numpy had a `diag` function or variable defined? same if you import another package after numpy and it happens to have it's own `arange` function, you will looes numpy's arange function.
Prefer explicit imports to star imports.

Comment: I see! Thank you and I will def keep the asterisk in mind. I have a follow up question, what is a constant array?

Comment: Please accept the solution if it answers your question. A constant array is an array that is constant i.e. in a mathematical context it can be an array of coefficients where the coefficients are constant.